# How to get IEditorOperations from IVsTextView?

Tags: visual-studio, menuitem, visual-studio-extensions, vs-community-edition

I'm developing my first Visual Studio (2015 Community) Command Menu and I'm trying to get access to `IEditorOperations` to delete text, send backspace etc. but I'm not sure how to. I can do:

```
var Service = Provider.GetService(typeof(IEditorOperationsFactoryService)) as IEditorOperationsFactoryService;
Service.GetEditorOperations(???);
```

I'm not sure what to pass in the `???` since I don't have access to an `ITextView` instead what I have is a `IVsTExtView` via:

```
IVsTextView View;
IVsTextManager Manager = (IVsTextManager)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsTextManager));
int MustHaveFocus = 1;
Manager.GetActiveView(MustHaveFocus, null, out View);
```

When creating the Command Menu, VS generates a template for me with a private ctor creating the command service, binding it to the command set id etc. An overridden `Initialize` method, and a bunch of properties.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:** After help from Sergey, I managed to get a bit further. But now I get a null when I try to get the `IEditorOperationsFactoryService`, all the other values are valid.

```
static IEditorOperations GetEditorService(IServiceProvider Provider, IVsTextView VsView)
    {
        IEditorOperations Result;

        try
        {
            var Model = (IComponentModel)Provider.GetService(typeof(SComponentModel));
            var Editor = (IEditorOperationsFactoryService)Provider.GetService(typeof(IEditorOperationsFactoryService)); // returns null

            var Adaptor = Model.GetService<IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService>();
            IWpfTextView TextView = Adaptor.GetWpfTextView(VsView);
            Result = Editor.GetEditorOperations(TextView);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
            Result = null;
        }

        return (Result);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get IEditorOperationsFactoryService instance from variable named Model, like this:

```
var Model = (IComponentModel)this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(SComponentModel));

var Editor = (IEditorOperationsFactoryService)Model.GetService<IEditorOperationsFactoryService>();
```

Comment: The generic version works for some reason but the non-generic one returns null. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can get [IWpfTextView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.text.editor.iwpftextview.aspx) (that implements ITextView) from IVsTextView using:

```
IVsTextView textView = ...;
IWpfTextView v = GetEditorAdaptersFactoryService().GetWpfTextView(textView);

private Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService GetEditorAdaptersFactoryService()
{
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.IComponentModel componentModel =
        (Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.IComponentModel)serviceProvider.GetService(
            typeof(Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.SComponentModel));
    return componentModel.GetService<Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService>();
}
```

Comment: `Editor` doesn't exist inside `VisualStudio` namepsace, nor `ComponentModelHost`. Do I need to reference a certain assembly?

Comment: IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService is defined in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.dll. IComponentModel is defined in Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.dll.

Comment: Now I get a null when getting `IEditorOperationsFactoryService` back from `GetService`. Please see edits.