# How to get IWpfTextView from command Visual Studio Extension 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-extensions

I need to show popup use TextViewAdornment, it's require IWpfTextView.
There is old code to that:

```
private IWpfTextView GetWpfTextView(IVsTextView vTextView)
{
   IWpfTextView view = null;
   IVsUserData userData = vTextView as IVsUserData;

   if (null != userData)
   {
      IWpfTextViewHost viewHost;
      object holder;
      Guid guidViewHost = DefGuidList.guidIWpfTextViewHost;
      userData.GetData(ref guidViewHost, out holder);
      viewHost = (IWpfTextViewHost)holder;
      view = viewHost.TextView;
   }
   return view;
}
```

but when go to Visual studio 2017 Extension DefGuidList.guidIWpfTextViewHost is missing. So I cannot get IWpfTextView anymore.

Please help me.
Thank you everyone.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/41215263/84507

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: For other people: you must add reference manual. Add Reference -> Assemblies -> Extensions then choose Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost and Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor

Comment: @Tan Nguyen, So this issue has been resolved, am I right? If so, would you   please post the solution as an answer? So you could mark it as the answer later and help other community members who get the same issue as yours.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After Sergey Vlasov answer I found a solution:

```
private IWpfTextView GetWpfView()
{
        var textManager = (IVsTextManager)ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(SVsTextManager));
        var componentModel = (IComponentModel)this.ServiceProvider.GetService(typeof(SComponentModel));
        var editor = componentModel.GetService<IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService>();

        textManager.GetActiveView(1, null, out IVsTextView textViewCurrent);
        return editor.GetWpfTextView(textViewCurrent);
}
```

You must add some reference manual by Add Reference -> Assemblies -> Extensions. Then choose:

```
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost 
 Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here, please mark it as the answer, have a nice day:)